# Need to Move Navigation Menu that is tied to Hamburger Menu

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I have a hamburger menu icon that is linked to a dropdown navigation menu at (top left side of screen) as shown in following link:

http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/index2.html

I want to make it so when the the hamburger menu (3 bars) are clicked, the menu drops flush to where the top nav bar ends. So right now you can see the top nav bars color underneath the drop down. It is sort of hard to explain, but I want it to look more like this picture at below link:

http://integratedresourcemgmt.com/navmen.html

I just want it so there isn't the overlaying color making it seem disjointed, in a sense.

I tried moving the hamburger menu down and I couldn't get it right. I was thinking that since I can adjust the size of the navigation-menu (width, padding) there must be away to move it down without moving the hamburger and nav exit icons/rollovers. I have been fooling with this for a while and am just not sure if it is possible? Any ideas? Thanks so much. -Beth

Comment: I am slowly answering my question, but I am not there yet. I adjusted the css for the following:    #navigation-wrapper top to 150px and the hamburger wrap top to 80px. This gets the alignment right, but it doesn't look so good smashed all the way down on the screen, so I have to figure out the next step?

Comment: O.K. this is now working in part. I put the #hamburger - top:30px & #navigation-wrapper #nav_exit - top:-110px.  Now I just need to figure out how to move the tabs #navigation-tabs table td up about 30px. Can't figure it out. Any ideas?